# Potential Metric on $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing

As part of a problem set for a course in Metric Spaces. I have to prove that the following is a metric for $\mathbb R ^n $:

$$ d_m (\mathbf x , \mathbf y) = \max_{i=1}  ^ n  | x_i -y_i| $$

Now I am quite confident that I can prove that the above satisfies the metric axioms $ (M1)- (M3) $. However, it has been impressed on us rather strongly that when dealing with a potential metric that we do not forget to how that $d_m$ is indeed a mapping from $X \times  X $ to $\Bbb R$.

I want this to become a habit so I am resolved to do this in the most basic of examples. I set out to prove that $d_m$ is well-defined. My attempt is below. I am a little suspicious of my attempt and I would like you thoughts and suggestions, as well as whether proving that $d_m$ is well-defined is enough to show that $d_m: X\times X \to \mathbb R$?

**My Attempt:**

Let $ \mathbf x = ( x_1, x_2,\cdots, x_n), \mathbf y = ( y_1, y_2,\cdots, y_n), \mathbf u = ( u_1, u_2,\cdots, u_n) \text{ and } \mathbf v = ( v_1, v_2,\cdots, v_n)$ such that $\mathbf x = \mathbf u$ and  $\mathbf x = \mathbf v$.

We have that: 
$$ \mathbf x = \mathbf u \iff  x_i = u_i \text{   } \forall i \in 1, \cdots,n.  $$ 
So $|x_i -y_i| = |u_i -v_i|$ for all $i \in 1,\cdots,n$. Now since the sets $\{|x_i -y_i|\}$ and $\{|u_i -v_i|\}$ are both finite the maximum of each exists and since $\{|x_i -y_i|\} =\{|u_i -v_i|\}$ so $\max_{i=1}^n  |x_i-y_i| = max_{i=1}^n |u_i -v_i| $. i.e. $ d_m(\mathbf x, \mathbf y) = d_m(\mathbf u, \mathbf v)$

Comment: I guess you want someone to check wether your attempt is correct, right? Maybe you want to add the tag 'proof check'. Other then that it seems correct and your reasoning is fine.

Comment: @noctusraid Done, sir

Comment: You proved that the two sets are finite, but you didn't explain why their maximums should be the same.

Comment: @5xum Well the sets are equal

Comment: @5xum as I read it he deduces that the maximum is the same as the two sets are equal ($\vert x_i-y_i\vert=\vert u_i-v_i\vert \forall i \in \{1,\dots ,n\}$) and so the remaining concern is wether is exists or not.

Comment: @PeterBlake I know they are, but you didn't say that.

Comment: @noctusraid So according to you, this part of the proof is ok?

Comment: @PeterBlake yes.

Comment: @noctusraid I am really worried about the notation $\{|x_i-y_i|\}$

Comment: what exactly bothers you? $\vert x_i - y_i \vert$ is just a positive real number, so by adding the curly brackets it becomes a subset of $\mathbb R$. ($a \in \mathbb R$, $\{a\} \subset \mathbb R$)

Comment: @noctusraid Well, it is meant to be shorthand for $\{|x_1 -y_1|,|x_2 -y_2|,\cdots, |x_n -y_n|\}$

Comment: @5xum I fixed it. So as it stands now is it ok?

Comment: @PeterBlake Looks good to me. Overcomplicated, but valid.